# How to prevent particles (hair) from being affected from wind

Tags: physics

I'm creating a scene with grass made from particles hair, but I'm using wind to affect the clouds which are also made from particles (emitter), the wind affects the grass and bend it which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Particle Settings under  **Field Weights** you can control influences of forces.

Set **Wind** to **0**.

[image]